# com.baomidou.dynamic.datasource.exception.CannotFindDataSourceException: dynamic-datasource can not find primary datasource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

com.baomidou.dynamic.datasource.exception.CannotFindDataSourceException: dynamic-datasource can not find primary datasource
at com.baomidou.dynamic.datasource.DynamicRoutingDataSource.determinePrimaryDataSource(DynamicRoutingDataSource.java:97)
at com.baomidou.dynamic.datasource.DynamicRoutingDataSource.getDataSource(DynamicRoutingDataSource.java:126)
at com.baomidou.dynamic.datasource.DynamicRoutingDataSource.determineDataSource(DynamicRoutingDataSource.java:83)
at com.baomidou.dynamic.datasource.ds.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:55)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:330)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.getProduct(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doDataSourceHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:105)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:100)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:94)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:41)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getLoggedHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:172)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:145)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:156)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:141)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:81)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:88)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:74)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:97)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10:26:08.070 [RMI TCP Connection(5)-10.21.102.209] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/] - [log,173] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
10:26:26.590 [nacos-grpc-client-executor-16] INFO  c.a.n.c.r.client - [printIfInfoEnabled,60] - [4d6ce7ac-dc84-43d7-b6cb-79073a6368a9_config-0] Receive server push request, request = ConfigChangeNotifyRequest, requestId = 17
10:26:26.591 [nacos-grpc-client-executor-16] INFO  c.a.n.c.r.client - [printIfInfoEnabled,60] - [4d6ce7ac-dc84-43d7-b6cb-79073a6368a9_config-0] Ack server push request, request = ConfigChangeNotifyRequest, requestId = 17
10:26:27.525 [nacos.client.cachedata.internal.notifier] WARN  c.a.c.n.c.NacosPropertySourceBuilder - [loadNacosData,87] - Ignore the empty nacos configuration and get it based on dataId[sanxin-order] & group[DEFAULT_GROUP]
10:26:27.528 [nacos.client.cachedata.internal.notifier] WARN  c.a.c.n.c.NacosPropertySourceBuilder - [loadNacosData,87] - Ignore the empty nacos configuration and get it based on dataId[sanxin-order.yml] & group[DEFAULT_GROUP]

As above,I can't run the OrderApplication. In nacos，my admin.yml like that

`spring:  datasource: dynamic: druid: initial-size: 5 min-idle: 5 maxActive: 20 maxWait: 60000 primary: master datasource: master: driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=true&serverTimezone=GMT%2B8 username: test password: test`

The AdminApplication read the admin.yml in nacos,and it worked.But when i run the OrderApplication,and read the order.yml,it can't worked,and the order.yml:

`spring:  redis: host: localhost port: 6379 datasource: dynamic: primary: master  strict: false     mybatis-plus: typeAliasesPackage: com.sanxin.order mapperLocations: classpath:mapper/**/*.xml`

I tried to add the mysql database datasource like url,username,password in order.yml,the OrderApplication can worked,but this way make the multiple database origin invalid,so i can't do like that.
I tried to add extension-configs in  OrderApplication/bootstrap.yml, just like:

`extension-configs: - dataId: admin.yml group: DEFAULT_GROUP`

And the Application worked,too.But i don't know the property would make the multipl database invalid or not.
So What Can I do to make the OrderApplication Run?

Answer (score 0):

1. CannotFindDataSourceException indicates that the program cannot run because of unable to load datasource configuration from the configuration file, and  there are no datasource configuration in order.yml.
2. Either specify a datasource in order.yml or get reference to admin.yml, you bring in datasource conf and solve the problem.
3. Where and How to specify the datasource has nothing to do whether multiple-database takes effect, what you need to do is adding multiple

```
spring:
 datasource:
  dynamic:
   datasource:
```

in config files (don't forget to specify the primary data sources), also see the document: https://www.kancloud.cn/tracy5546/dynamic-datasource/2264611

Comment: It sounds like my order.yml can't get reference to admin.yml,i checked my order.yml and can't find any wrong in format and configuration,and my adminApplication can run,what should i do then?And my order.yml in nacos like that:
`
spring: 
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
  datasource:
    dynamic:
       primary: master 
       strict: false
`

Comment: Your adminApplication can run because the config it refers contains datasource info, and OrderApplication can't run because `order.yml` doesn't contain datasource info. You can resolve it in several ways, as you have done before: 1. add datasource conf in `order.yml`, and  OrderApplication can load proper datasource from nacos'config file; 2. declare reference to admin.yml, so OrderApplication can load the same datasouce as AdminApplication. 3: if OrderApplication and AdminApplication use the same datasource config, you can extract the datasource config and refer to it in both app.

Comment: in summary, what you have done is right, and there is no need to worry about make the multiple database origin invalid.  (If you have any reference that add datasource config in `order.yml` would make the multiple database origin invalid, please tell me)

Comment: Thanks,i have been declared referecnes use "primary:master"config in order.yml,it should be work in OrderApplication,but it not work now,and that is make me confuse .I read lots of manuals and anwsers,and tried it.Only the direct connect in nacos config(add datasource conf in order.yml) and add` extension-config` in OrderApplication/bootstrap.yml this two ways can make the OrderApplication run.Otherwise,the direct sounds like will be make the multiple nymanic switch invalid(sorry,not clearly in above),so i can't use the first method,the second one i can't sure is it a direct connect

Comment: I think you misunderstand the `primary:master` config. It only specify which datasource is used as master when you have multiple datasource config,  so it can't help you get concret datasource config(jdbc-url, user...) from nacos. BTW, I wonder what you mean by `multiple dynamic switch`, because I think you can edit the config in nacos to switch the database. (Any chinese blog is welcome if you can find one to describe your demand)

Comment: Well,the **primary:master**  choose the master datasource,and the master datasource (like url username password etc)was defined in admin.yml,this is my understand about it.The `multiple dynamic switch` is my misunderstand from others converse,just forget it.In my above describe,i think my config would  be worked,[link](https://www.cnblogs.com/ziyue7575/p/e97bcad8ed323602251ca3bd2b1a4457.html)This is the blog example i saw before.I see enormous configs are similar like that,and also my config,but my config doesn't work.BTW,i just config a datasource now(I'm not sure is it would be a factor.)